# C++ vector push_back()

Tags: c++

I just saw in a tutorial someone who used in the same file both:

```
myVector.back().push_back();

myVector.push_back();
```

What's the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first had to be something like

```
vector<vector<T>>
```

Otherwise it would not work. `back()` returns the element at the back of the `vector`. When you say

```
myVector.back().push_back();
```

it would be accessing the last `vector<T>`, then calling `push_back()` on that inner `vector`

If it is the case that `myVector` is a `vector<vector<T>>`, then

```
myVector.push_back();
```

would be pushing back an empty `vector<T>` whereas

```
myVector.back().push_back();
```

would be pushing back a default `T` onto the last `vector<T>` in `myVector`.

Comment: In my case myVector is a vector containing a class

Comment: In that case, `back()` would return an instance of your class that was the last element in the `vector`. So unless your class has a `push_back()` method, then the first version will not compile.

Comment: So if I got it right, back() points the last item in the vector and then the push_back() adds something to the end of this item.

Answer (score 1):

```
myVector may be a std::vector<std::vector<T>>
```